# Making update to AS400 from SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange, openquery

I'm trying to update something in AS400 from sql server 2000 through openquery like following.

```
UPDATE
OPENQUERY(odbcname, 'SELECT * FROM "libname"."filename" WITH NC')
SET NBFLAG01=1
WHERE NBFLAG01 <> 1
```

Here's the error I'm getting.

```
"OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' reported an error.  
[OLE/DB provider returned message: Insufficient base table information for updating or refreshing.]
OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDASQL' IRowsetChange::SetData returned 0x80004005:   ].
```

Answer (score 1):

Try listing your fields within the select. If anything to eliminate that as a problem.